# Parse.com Push on Android in Xamarin

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible to receive push notifications from Parse on Android using Xamarin?

I've been looking around online, but everything I've seen suggests this isn't possible. I'm able to register for push notifications on iOS using the REST service, but on Android I haven't been able to figure out how to properly register on Parse.

I was able to register for Google Cloud Messaging on my own google developer app, and received a device id, so I know that part should be able to work, but I'm unable to actually register that device in any way on the parse installation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now supported by Parse without doing any custom bindings.

http://blog.parse.com/announcements/push-net-push/

Answer (score 2):

You can always [bind the native Parse SDK for Android](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/) and use that in your Android App. Then do the same thing binding the native Parse SDK for iOS using objective sharpie. Thats how we got it working for our App. So to answer your initial question: Yes it is possible to receive push notifications from Parse on Android using Xamarin!

Comment: Is there a way to still easily set up all your parse objects to convert to standard .Net types?

Comment: Your binding can/will contain parse classes as .net representation mapped to their Objective-C counterparts. You can massage NSString properties into string properties and NSUInteger to uint for example. Same is true for Java/Android.